# Error when openvpn config uses "*" in route

Tags: openvpn

I'm trying to enable vpn only for specific hosts on mac

```
route-nopull
route *.dev1.com

dev tun
persist-tun

...
```

and getting the error:

Cannot resolve host address: *dev1.com: (nodename nor servname provided, or not known)

changing the config to

```
route d1.dev1.com
```

works perfectly

How do I add a range of subdomain hosts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

Routes work at the IP level. When you input `d1.dev1.com`, this is passed to `route` command, which resolves it and adds a route towards the specific target. It's not possible to resolve `*.dev1.com`, nor know all valid subdomains of a domain.

OpenVPN in `tun` mode is a L3 VPN. It operates at the IP layer, which means it cares about IP addresses, not DNS names. DNS names is resolved at a *higher* layer, and IP addresses is used by applications when opening sockets. Neither OpenVPN or the routing table cares about DNS. They only care about packets and IP addresses.

If you want that kind of redirection, you *have* to work at a higher layer. If your traffic is e.g. http(s), you can use a HTTP proxy such as Squid or Nginx to redirect it over your VPN.